# docker container has only internet when restarting docker.service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After my dedicated server crashed and a new network interface and new ubuntu 22.05 installation was made, I run into a very strange problem:

I have the standard nginx-proxy-manager docker compose file as an example, but the problem exists **on every container**:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # These ports are in format <host-port>:<container-port>
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port
      # Add any other Stream port you want to expose
      # - '21:21' # FTP

    # Uncomment the next line if you uncomment anything in the section
    # environment:
      # Uncomment this if you want to change the location of
      # the SQLite DB file within the container
      # DB_SQLITE_FILE: "/data/database.sqlite"

      # Uncomment this if IPv6 is not enabled on your host
      # DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'

    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

When i run `docker compose up` the container has no internet (i have spent hours try to fixing the problem without success).
Which I can see under the `docker compose logs`:

```
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:04:18 PM] [IP Ranges] › ℹ  info      Fetching IP Ranges from online services...
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:04:18 PM] [IP Ranges] › ℹ  info      Fetching https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:04:34 PM] [IP Ranges] › ✖  error     getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN ip-ranges.amazonaws.com
```

When I run `systemctl restart docker.service` and run `docker compose up` in the first few seconds, the container is reachable via `curl 127.0.0.1:81` and the logs shows:

```
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:08:17 PM] [IP Ranges] › ℹ  info      Fetching IP Ranges from online services...
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:08:17 PM] [IP Ranges] › ℹ  info      Fetching https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:08:17 PM] [IP Ranges] › ℹ  info      Fetching https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:08:17 PM] [IP Ranges] › ℹ  info      Fetching https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6
nginx-pm-app-1  | [8/27/2023] [1:08:17 PM] [SSL      ] › ℹ  info      Let's Encrypt Renewal Timer initialized
```

When I run `docker compose down` followed by `docker compose up` I get the same problem, that I have the fetching error in the docker compose logs as well as:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:81
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

The only thing I realize is, that when the docker container has internet, I can see under `docker inspect nginx-pm-app-1`:

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "5b4a5cc425ceb746dbef9d3afaf67bda28660e545b1d7a2fffc974732b163053",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ],
                "81/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "81"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "81"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

While when it has Internet is shows:

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "4db63152ce5c2493f54cca778174dd5614a547f195bb591c5c62c7e1bcf2404a",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ],
                "81/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "81"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "81"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

But I assume this is just a side effect of the root cause...

i have tested to set the DNS server in the daemon.json, as well as playing with ipconf, and --bip in the systemctl file...
the network: host solution is working, but this is not the intention of docker to run containers like that.

Thank you for your help, as I really despairing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem and I don't know if this is based on the standard ubuntu installation or if this is from my server host (in this case Strato):

I have two servers. One dedicated server and one virtual server. Both with a fresh ubuntu install and standard docker installation. The v-server ran fine, while the dedicated server had the problems mentioned in the first post. I compared everything and found the error in the network interface configuration.

The v-server network configuration is set only to "*en" networks, while the d-server had all networks " * ". This caused that all network interfaces (including the one from docker) will be configured as "configured network", which is obviously not working with the docker network. I changed the config to be applied only on the "*en" network, restarted the system and everything is working fine now. The docker network is now unmanaged, which should be the solution to that specific problem.

**Short solution summary:**

*(DANGER: this does not cover every ubuntu solution and every possible network interface! be aware what you are doing! Once you made a wrong setting you might cannot connect to your server anymore!)*

- Check `networkctl` --> docker network should be **unmanaged**.
- **If not**: `ip link show` and identify your network interface name. Usually it starts with "eth..." or "enp..." for ethernet connections on newer ubuntu installs. wifi might differ!
- `ls -l /etc/netplan` to get the network config file
- `nano *network config file path*`
- edit the match / name to the network interface you identfied above (in example enp* or eth*) - don't mess that up!

```
network:
   version: 2
   ethernets:
     mainif:
       match:
         name: 'enp*'
(...)
```

- restart server
- `networkctl` --> docker network should be unmanaged, while your network interface is configured